# Read and write on the same node (central) using an RF24 network on Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to send and receive on the same node using the RF24Network library, but I'm unable to do so even when I use `radio.StopListening()`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <RF24Network.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <SPI.h>

RF24 radio(9,10);
RF24Network network(radio);
struct payload_t{unsigned long int code; unsigned long int message;};

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
  radio.setAutoAck(false);
  network.begin(108, 0);
}

void loop(){
  network.update();
  RF24NetworkHeader header;
  payload_t payload;
  if(network.available()) {
    network.read(header, &payload, sizeof(payload));
    Serial.println(payload.message);
    // I WANT HERE TO SEND BACK TO THE TRANSMITTER but I'm unable to do that
    radio.stopListening();
    payload_t payload = { 2000, 15444452 };
    RF24NetworkHeader header(2);
    network.write(header, &payload, sizeof(payload));
  }
}
```

Second Node:

```
#include <RF24Network.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <SPI.h>

RF24 radio(9,10);
RF24Network network(radio);
struct payload_t{unsigned long int code; unsigned long int message;};
firstExec = 1;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
  radio.setAutoAck(false);
  network.begin(108, 2);
}

void loop() {
  network.update();
  if(firstExec) {
    radio.stopListening();
    payload_t payload = { 2000, 5555555 };
    RF24NetworkHeader header(0);
    network.write(header, &payload, sizeof(payload));
    radio.startListening();
    firstExec = 0;
  }
  RF24NetworkHeader header;
  payload_t payload;
  if(network.available()) {
    network.read(header, &payload, sizeof(payload));
    Serial.println(payload.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the part of your code you are having problems with?

Comment: How about including your attempt to send data so we can see where you went wrong?

Comment: Sorry for that, here is the full script with the sending code.

Comment: How about the code for the other node?

Comment: Sorry for missing the network.update() because i copied just the necessary code and as I always put this in the top of the loop I missed it up when I copied

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been abandoned in unanswerable form for over a year.

Answer (score 1):

The library says you must include `network.update()` in `loop()` for the nodes to be in sync. Place that call at the top of `loop()` in both nodes.